# ASMX Dependency Injection and IoC

Tags: dependencies, inversion-of-control, asmx, code-injection

I have gotten stuck while trying to get my `asmx` web service to use dependency injection and using an IoC to do it. I want my webservice to be able to use my internal business layer services. The webservice is to be used by an external client from a different domain and will mainly be used to send and receive information about entities such as Orders and Customers.

An example would be:

```cs
public class MyService : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    [WebMethod]
    public string HelloWorld()
    {
        return new MyBusinessService().MyMethod();
    } 
}

public class MyBusinessService : IMyBusinessService
{
    public string MyMethod()
    {
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

I want to use dependency injection to eliminate the need for "newing" up my service but I can't figure out a way to do this. I can get it to work using poor mans DI.

Like this:

```cs
public class MyService : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    private IMyBusinessService _myService;

    public MyService(IMyBusinessService myService)
    {
        _myService = myService;
    }

    public MyService() : this(new MyBusinessServie()) { }

    [WebMethod]
    public string HelloWorld()
    {
        return _myService.MyMethod();
    }
}
```

But I can't work out how to use a IoC container to inject my dependencies because I can't get the service to run without  a parameterless constructor.
I have just started to test dependency injection and got it to work fine on my windows forms application with StructureMap but got stuck on this one.

Answer (score 43):

Unfortunately there isn't any way for one to perform constructor injection with web services in ASP.NET.  It is a requirement of ASP.NET that you provide a default constructor.  The constructor of MyService is about as close to the composition root that you can get with this type of web service, without using a DI container.

With ASP.NET it is not unusual to have multiple composition roots.  Which can be the constructors of the individual web services and web pages.  If you are using ASP.NET MVC it is the ControllerFactory, which is more DI friendly.

With your implementation the important part isn't to move the construction of the object graph from the web service, as this is your composition root.  The main thing to do, is to keep the web service as thin as possible, keep most of the logic in the dependency so it can be tested, or reused.  Pulling information out of the HTTP headers is an example of a task that the web service could to then pass off that information to the dependency.

A good book to refer to for DI patterns and techniques is [Dependency Injection in .NET](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1935182501) by Mark Seemann.

If your web service implemented `System.Web.IHttpHandler` instead of deriving from `System.Web.Services.WebService` you could implement your DI like so:

Global.ashx.cs

```
public class Global : HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_PreRequestHandlerExecute(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var context = ((HttpApplication)sender).Context;

        var needsMyBusinessService = context.Handler as INeedMyBusinessService;
        if (needsMyBusinessService != null)
            needsMyBusinessService.MyBusinessService = new MyBusinessService();
    }
}
```

MyService.ashx.cs

```
public class MyService : IHttpHandler, INeedMyBusinessService
{
    public IMyBusinessService MyBusinessService { get; set; }

    public bool IsReusable { get { return true; } }

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        // uses my dependency
    }
}
```

INeedMyBusinessService.cs

```
public interface INeedMyBusinessService
{
    IMyBusinessService MyBusinessService { get; set; }
}
```

However the catch with this implementation is that is does **not** work with web services that implement `System.Web.Services.WebService` as the web service object is not initialized until after the `PreRequestHandlerExecute` event is call, which is the last event before `ProcessRequest` is called.

The above example works if you want to have a unique instance for each web service.  If you wanted to have the same instance (Singleton lifecycle) of `MyBusinessService` for each web service request you could implement the Global.ashx.cs file like so:

```
public class Global : HttpApplication
{
    private static IMyBusinessService businessService;

    protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Global.businessService = new MyBusinessService();
    }

    protected void Application_PreRequestHandlerExecute(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var context = ((HttpApplication)sender).Context;

        var needsMyBusinessService = context.Handler as INeedMyBusinessService;
        if (needsMyBusinessService != null)
            needsMyBusinessService.MyBusinessService = Global.businessService;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can only have a parameter-less constructor on a WebService. However, what you could do, is have a property on the WebService class, and inside of the parameter-less constructor call something like _myDependency = container.resolve();

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question and unlikely to help very many people, but you basically need `IDependencyResolver` and `IDependencyScope` implementations that when ServiceProvider::GetService() fails to return an instance of a requested type, the type is *explicitly instanced* (ideally using the container to resolve ctor parameters.)

The type can be "explicitly instanced" using reflection, or, using something modern like `ActivatorUtilities.GetServiceOrCreateInstance(...)`

By default, when the dependency resolver does not provide an instance of a requested type for a controller, page, module (webservice), etc the runtime will attempt to use the de facto `Activator` class to create an instance, and `Activator` can only create instances of types which have a public, parameterless constructor.

So to say that your type requires a public, parameterless ctor is only partially true.. if you are unable/unwilling to create `IDependencyResolver` /  `IDependencyScope` implementations.  A custom dependency resolver impl is a trivial thing to implement, and MSDN has articles and examples of basic implementations.

The only other thing you require is the obvious DI container with type registrations, and an `IDependencyResolver` registered with ASP.NET that leverages your DI container. Today that would likely be something like `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection` but for the date and content of the question it could also have been `Unity` (the dependency injection framework, not the game engine.) Configuring and integrating a DI container is a bit beyond the scope of a Q&A, and there may be other Q&As already which cover doing that. I will note that if you're building your own IDependencyResolver, you also have the options of using a more modern DI framework (such as the one used within ASP.NET Core scaffolds) even though you may be using an ASP.NET version from the 2000s.  The underlying DI framework is irrelevant, the Dependency Resolver is what is key here.

See Also:

- [The Web API Dependency Resolver (microsoft.com)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/dependency-injection?source=recommendations#the-web-api-dependency-resolver); what you need to know, talks of Unity but any DI container/framework can be used in its place.
- [Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.activatorutilities); for a more forgiving approach.
- [Type.GetConstructors Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.getconstructors); for a DIY approach

HTH!