# Error 'Page does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments' with ASP.net WebForm and autofac

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, autofac

Is it possible to configure Autofac to work with ASP.NET  Webforms to use Dependency Injection

my Global Code :

```
 static IContainerProvider _containerProvider;

    public IContainerProvider ContainerProvider
    {
        get { return _containerProvider; }
    }

    protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        builder.RegisterType<EmployeeManager>().As<IEmployeeManager>().InstancePerRequest();
        _containerProvider = new ContainerProvider(builder.Build());
    }
```

My Page Code :

```
 private readonly IEmployeeManager _empManager;
    public WebForm2(IEmployeeManager empManager)
    {
        _empManager = empManager;
    }
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _empManager.GetAllEmployees();
    }
```

Error :
[image: Error]

Comment: There is an entire section of [the docs](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/integration/aspnet.html) dedicated to ASP.NET integration, with several sections on dependency injection.

Comment: i edit my post with code i follow all steps still not working (webform.aspx oes not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments)

Comment: @salah Don't just tell us you followed all steps. List each step you performed in your post and show relevant configuration. A little hint: Web Forms doesn't support constructor injection, just property injection. So you clearly didn't follow all the steps.

Comment: it is worked now but what about inject in asmx file?

Answer (score 2):

> In order to inject dependencies into web forms pages (`System.Web.UI.Page` instances) or user controls (`System.Web.UI.UserControl` instances) you must expose their dependencies as public properties that allow setting. This enables the `PropertyInjectionModule` to populate those properties for you. 
>   > http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/integration/webforms.html

Due to internal restriction in ASP.net WebForm, constructor injection in page is not possible. Only property injection is allowed within ASP.net WebForm Pages. The [documentation](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/integration/webforms.html) explain how to deal with this restriction.

Comment: if i want inject in asmx file ?

Comment: Why do you use asmx instead of WCF ? By the way this question may help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7845791/asmx-dependency-injection-and-ioc